# Build Linear Regression model in Python without SK Learn

Tags: python, regression

I am trying to build a Linear Regression model without using SK learn package. For a single independent variable I have the code (given by my professor) which is below:

```
def get_gradient(w, x, y):
   y_estimate = (np.power(x,1).dot(w)).flatten() #hypothesis
   error = (y.flatten() - y_estimate) 
   mse = (1.0/len(x))*np.sum(np.power(error,2)) # mse
   gradient = -(1.0/len(x)) * error.dot(np.power(x,1))         # gradient
   return gradient, mse
w = np.random.randn(2) # Random Intialization
alpha = 0.5 # learning rate
tolerance = 1e-3 # param for stopping the loop
print("Intial values of Weights:")
print(w[1], w[0])

# Perform Gradient Descent

iterations = 1
while True:
    gradient, error = get_gradient(w, train_x, train_y)
    new_w = w - alpha * gradient

# Stopping Condition
    if np.sum(abs(new_w - w)) < tolerance:
        print ("Converged")
        break

# Print error every 10 iterations
    if iterations % 10 == 0:
        print ("Iteration: %d - Error: %.4f" %(iterations, error))
        print ("Updated Weights : {:f} , {:f}".format(w[1], w[0]))
iterations += 1
w = new_w

print ("Final Weights : {:f} , {:f}".format(w[1], w[0]))
print ("Test Cost =", get_gradient(w, test_x, test_y)[1])
```

This works fine with one variable (+ the intercept). Note - created a numpy array for x and y each for purpose of this code.

But now I wish to use this on the Boston Housing Dataset which has 13 Independent variables/features.

I cannot figure out how to use this for multiple variables. I cannot figure out how to:

1. Have each weight work with only the values in the column of one variable - apply gradient descent and recalculate the weight. If I try to run the gradient descent function with 13 weights inside the weights array - it ends up (I think) multiplying all 13 weights with ALL rows in EACH variable. I think this is what is happening because initially, I got 'error' as infinity after only a few iterations. Also, it got thrown into an infinite loop.
2. I tried running a for loop for each weight in the weights variable (13 variables) and THEN calculating gradient for each of the 13 variables. I then put each weight in a list (later converted to numpy array) before calling the 'get gradient' function in the while loop. This worked, at the time but error reached infinity and the program went into an infinite loop just like before. Anyway, this should not even be a solution since by doing a for loop I am making the first variable get all the relevant weight first.
3. I also tried to divide all the weights and errors by 13 - to at least get the program to run and then I would tweak it. But no success there either.

Strangely I cannot replicate the for loop anymore. I keep getting some or the error - shape errors, value errors etc.

Please help.

If any further information is required - please do let me know.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You don't need to use gradient descent for linear regression. It has a closed form solution.  Just form the model matrix `X`, then compute the regression coefficients with `b = (X'X)^(-1) X'Y` in one line. If the data is very large then there are other methods which avoid inverting X'X

Comment: Ill try this and revert shortly. But the assignment specifically asks to implement Gradient Descent. Any thoughts on that?